# Getting the location of the users with PHP Facebook Client Library

Tags: facebook, location

I'm using PHP Facebook Client Library for my fb app and I want to know how can I get info about the users that authorize my app. For example how can get their location, age or other info available?

Answer (score 0):

you need to request these parameters through the authorization url:
user_location, user_about_me....

Read some more at:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the access token for that user, and after that:

```
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $access_token;
```

it returns user data.